# Записать ссылку на переменную в массив

Tags: массивы, javascript, ссылки, строки

Вопрос: Как записать ссылку на переменную в массив?
Задача: Я делаю функцию которая принимает строку вида `"ключ1=значение1;ключ2=значение2;"` разбивает её на пары **ключ**=>**значение** и соответсвующей **ключ**ю **переменной** присваивает **значение** Короче вот код:

```
function setParam(parameters){
    var keyvals=[
    ["title","this.$title$"],
    ["minimized","this.$minimized$"]
    ]
    for(var i in keyvals){
        if(parameters.hasOwnProperty(keyvals[i][0])){
            eval(keyvals[i][1]+"=parameters."+keyvals[i][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

После выполнения кода setParam({title:"Заголовок",minimized:true}); переменной `this.$title$` присваивается строка `"Заголовок"` а переменной `this.$minimized$` присваивается **строка `"false"`** 
Я думаю что после обусфикации кода имена переменных будут переименованы (в том числе `this.$title$` например в `this.e`) но обусфикатор не изменит строки (имена переменных соответствующих **ключю**) в массиве

```
var keyvals=[
        ["title","this.$title$"],
        ["minimized","this.$minimized$"]
        ]
```

А можно ли в массив записать **ссылки** на переменные чтобы например код:

```
var b=2;
var c=["keyword",b];
if(c[0]=="keyword") c[1]=6;
alert(c[1]);
```

выводил не 2 а 6 т.е чтобы в `c=[1]` присваивалось не значение переменной **`b`** а именно ссылка на переменную **`b`**?
Есть вариант присваивать значения переменным соответствующим ключам в ручную так

```
function setParam(parameters){
  this.$title$=parameters.title;        
}
```

Тогда обусфикатор переименует всё правильно но если таких как title параметров много
то придётся писать много кода так что это не выход!
**UPD**: Исправил ошибку со строкой "false" вместо булевого значения

```
eval(keyvals[i][1]+"=parameters[keyvals["+i+"][0]]");
```

PS: Незнаете ли вы другой вариант написания функции `setParam`?
Буду рад любой помощи в решении проблемы :)

Comment: А вы, однако, суровы

     eval(keyvals[i][1]+"=parameters."+keyvals[i][0]);

Comment: Что значит "А вы, однако, суровы"? я не понял?

Comment: .

     keyvals[i][1] = parameters['keyvals'][i][0]; // не?..

Comment: Вы не поняли иерархию моего кода!  keyvals[i][1] = parameters['keyvals'][i][0]; это  совсем не то что я хочу (это к тому же неработает) та и проблема не в eval'e!

Comment: Напишу откровенно - вы не абсолютно не понимаете языка, соответственно мыслите о каком-то идиотизме, либо неправильно выражаете свои мысли кодом, в любом случае, ИМХО, за выполнение строковых значений вида `this.$title$` через eval, после смерти, нужно напрямую отправлять в ад...

Comment: Так вы мне наконец скажите как в массив записать ССЫЛКУ на переменную или вы "Такой умный" а помочь не можете? :)

Comment: Спасибо а я и не подумал об этом преобразуйте в ответ я отмечу!

Comment: [дубликат](http://hashcode.ru/questions/102526/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не вижу ничего сложного:

```
keyvals = {};

keyvals["title"]=this.$title$;
keyvals["minimized"]=this.$minimized$;

keyvals["title"]=parameters["title"];
```

и работайте дальше в коде с `keyvals`,

зачем вам массивы, ума не приложу